# Vue2 navigate to external url with location.href

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I tried to go to 'www.mytargeturl.org' using router.go, router.push, router.replace and window.location.href to redirect my vuejs app but i always get myVueapp.com/www.mytargeturl.org
Here's my route:

```
  routes:[
{path: '/', component: App,
  children:[
    {
      path: 'detail',
      component: ItemDetail,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: 'search',
      component: Middle
    }       
  ]
},   
{
  path: '/test', component: Test
},
{ path: '/a', redirect: 'www.mytargeturl.org' } // also tried this but didnt work
```

]

Comment: just use a regular `a` tag. vue-router is for navigating inside your app

Comment: It's simple: don't use vue-router, because it will redirect to an internal link (i.e. within the app). Use `window.location` and that should work just fine.

Comment: I have already tried window.location before posting here but no success. Here's my sample: https://jsfiddle.net/alvirtuoso/dkb1d13h/

Answer (score 44):

Agreed with the people in other comments. Vue's philosophy is not to solve already solved problems. Same here. Just use an ordinary `a` tag for the link whenever possible. If you need to go through the router though, use [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard):

```
{
    path: '/redirect',
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        // Put the full page URL including the protocol http(s) below
        window.location.replace("https://example.com")
    }
}
```

Comment: This still directs me internally like myvueapp.com/www.mytargeturl.org

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you need to use full page url with protocol e.g. https://www.google.com

Comment: I suggest adding this detail to this answer to make it clearer

Comment: Blows up in Typescript version of Vue
Error TS2322 (TS) Type '"http://example.com"' is not assignable to type 'Location'. D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\tsconfig.json D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\router\index.ts 145 Active

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted the code to use `location.redirect` which I think it the most appropriate in that scenario.

Answer (score 13):

Found the solution. By adding ***http*** in my target url, all is well! Like this
`window.location = 'http://mytargeturl.org"`

This seems to be universal javascript truth not just vue.

Comment: So you are saying `{ path: '/a', redirect: 'http://www.mytargeturl.org' }` worked for you?!  It doesn't for me.

Answer (score 6):

No need to use navigation guards in this case, cleaner to use [dynamic redirect](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) right there in route config

```
routes:[
  {
    path: '/redirect-example',
    redirect: (to: Route) => {
      window.location.href = 'http://example.com'
      return '/redirecting' // not important since redirecting
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Blows up in typescript verison of vueapp:

ERROR in D:/TFS/EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy/clientapp/src/router/index.ts(143,24):
143:24 Cannot find name 'Route'.

Comment: @Eric Brown it's a typescript thing, import the type, or if you are running with vanilla is, then drop it altogether

Answer (score 2):

In your route, set a meta property with the redirection url

```
{
  name: "Shop",
  path: "/shop",
  component: {},
  meta: { RedirectExternalUrl: "https://mystore.com" },
},
```

And setup a router guard function to do the work:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {

    // External redirect
    if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.RedirectExternalUrl)) {
        const url: string = to.meta.RedirectExternalUrl as string;
        window.location.replace(url);
        return;
    }

    next();
});
```