# Vue-router appending the same URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Whenever I try to use a simple

```
<router-link to="https://google.com">
    Google
</router-link>
```

it renders the link to `http://localhost:8080/https:/google.com`

**router.js**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
)}
```

and I have no `.env` file. Whenever I create the `.env` and add `BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080` it renders `http://localhost:8080/http:/localhost:8080/https:/google.com`

Have anyone experienced this issue?

**UPDATE**
The example above reflects external websites but this is also happening with internal links. Example:

```
<router-link avatar :to="{name: 'author', params: {id: author.id, name: author.name}}"> foo </router-link>
```

**definition author's route**

```
{
  path: '/author/:id/:name',
  name: 'author',
  component: Author
},
```

Everything was working okay some days ago but there must be something I added that changed this behaviour. I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find where all went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJs vue-router linking an external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633001/vuejs-vue-router-linking-an-external-website)

Comment: It's not a duplicated. I updated the answer to reflect how it's not a dup

Comment: @Charlie You need to update the question with your route definition for the `author` route, then.

Comment: @Charlie Also what the resulting URL in the browser winds up being for your `author` route. Is it  something like `http://localhost:8080/{name: 'author', params: {id: author.id, name: author.name}}`?

Comment: @ceejayoz the route for the author is: http://localhost:8080/author/348/Aaron%20Sorkin%0A 

Defining `base: undefined` at `router.js` solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a normal `<a href=""></a>` a href tag for external links. Vue-router and router-link are primarily for instance resources.

Comment: I updated the answer because this also happens with internal links

Comment: @Charlie Make sure you're using `:to` and not `to` for the internal links.

Answer (score 3):

This problem could be from your router. I'm guessing the `process.env.BASE_URL` would be `http://localhost:8080`. I faced similar problem then I ended up here. Unfortunately, the step above by @screll didn't solve my problem. What I did was to change the baseUrl.

> Change the baseUrl in your router to '/' instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

For clarity, These are the steps depending on the project setup, either `vue/cli or webpack setup`

```
// .env file
BASE_URL=/
# or VUE_APP_BASE_URL=/
```

Then, Router

```
// NB: The BASE_URL is '/'

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  // or base: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  routes
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to put "/" in your routes. Hence, it will just change the last segment of your url.

[image]

Without "/"

[image]

With "/"

[image]