# .vue file router link to external url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making changes to a navigation menu in a .vue file in my laravel application. I'm trying to link to an external url such as https://google.com but if I change the code to an  link, the link doesn't show when I compile.

I've tried changing to router-link to an external website, but it didn't work. It tries to go to that as a page /https://google.com

```
<li class="nav-item" @click="closePanel">
            <router-link class="nav-link" to="/campaigns">
                <i class="fal fa-layer-group"></i>
                <span>Campaigns</span>
            </router-link>
        </li>
<li class="nav-item" @click="closePanel">
            <router-link class="nav-link" to="https://google.com">
                <i class="fal fa-layer-group"></i>
                <span>External website</span>
            </router-link>
        </li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJs vue-router linking an external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633001/vuejs-vue-router-linking-an-external-website)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way is using

```
<li class="nav-item" @click="closePanel">
            <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fal fa-layer-group"></i>
                <span>External website</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using window.location.href . For e.g

```
<a href='redirectTo("https://google.com")'>Redirect to google</a>
```

And on methods defination of redirectTo

```
 methods:{ 
      redirectTo(url){
        window.location.href=url;      
       } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand two things-

1. `router-link` doesn't consider external URLs.
2. `router-link` can wrap one element.

To fix this, you fill prop `to` with any value and use an anchor tag inside this, like below-

```
<li class="nav-item" @click="closePanel">
 <router-link class="nav-link" to="https://google.com">
     <a href="https://google.com">
        <i class="fal fa-layer-group"></i>
        <span>External website</span>
     </a>
 </router-link>
</li>
```