# v-btn 'to' prop adds path to base url (localhost), how can I direct to another website?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

I'm using a Vue.js project setup with Nuxt and Vuetify.js.

I'm trying to add FontAwesome icons as `v-btn`s to lead the user to an Instagram page.

Unfortunately when clicking the icon, the browser is directed to `http://localhost:3000/https://www.instagram.com/therock/?hl=en` instead of just `https://www.instagram.com/therock/?hl=en` as expected. The Instagram account URL is tacked onto the end of the base URL.

Here's the `template` portion of the Vue file:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar app flat color="rgb(249, 249, 249)">
      <router-link to="/" class="toolbar-title">
        <v-toolbar-title>Chumiest Bucket</v-toolbar-title>
      </router-link>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          :to="item.path"
          flat
        >{{ item.name }}</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat :to="instagram.path">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="instagram.icon"/>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>

      <v-menu class="hidden-md-and-up">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon slot="activator"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <v-btn :to="item.path" flat>{{ item.name }}</v-btn>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-btn flat :to="instagram.path">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="instagram.icon"/>
          </v-btn>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>

    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content style="padding-top: 19px;">
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>

    <v-footer app style="position: absolute;">
      <span style="font-size: 8pt;">&copy; 2019 Chumiest Bucket</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

here's the `script` portion of the Vue file:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      fixed: false,
      items: [
        {
          name: 'About',
          path: '/about'
        },
        {
          name: 'Stuff',
          path: '/stuff'
        }
      ],
      instagram: {
        icon: ['fab', 'instagram'],
        path: 'https://www.instagram.com/therock/?hl=en'
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "to" prop is used for navigating to pages within your routes. See documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link). To navigate to external links, [Bind the url to href instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633001/vuejs-vue-router-linking-an-external-website).

```
<a :href="instagram.path">
  {{ url }}
</a>
```

Comment: Old but related: I have the same behavior with adding a url to an `<audio><source :src="[absoluteURL"></audio>`. There the base-url also gets prefixed. How can I undo that?