# Redirects on Google Cloud Run

Tags: redirect, seo, google-cloud-run

I've got a clients site that uses Google Cloud Run and I need to implement some redirects as they have both www. and a non www. version of the site simultaneously.

```
https://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

I would like to setup a redirect so that it goes from www. to the non www. version. I know I can't do this at DNS level for this type of redirect so am looking at doing it at a server level. I've checked for documentation on this on Google Cloud run and can't seem to see anything relevant. I've never worked with a client site that uses cloud run before, but have a good idea of how I'd go about doing this on a website that uses Apache or Nginx.

Does anyone know if there is a specific file where I should be implementing redirects within the Cloud Run setup?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You can't in Cloud Run. Use a HTTPS load balancer instead.

Comment: Your backend code running in Cloud run must implement the HTTP Redirect. This is easily done by most frameworks or simply processing the HTTP Host header.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the code. For example if you were using Python with Flask, you can implement it in your `@app.before_request`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I'm not really sure how I'd go about doing this kind of redirect in the code, it's a vue.js site.

Comment: I've found this but I'm not sure if this is something that will work for www. / non www. versions https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias

Comment: I don't think that will work. I'm not that familiar with routing in Vue.js. See if this stackoverflow answer sorts you out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598125/15211203 You should be able to get the full url by doing ```window.location.origin``` and then you check if it contains ```www``` in which case you redirect to the naked domain.